# CSS overflow:auto screwed up on ios and safari

Tags: css, overflow

i have a div with a fixed width and height. In the inside of this div
i have 6 more divs with content. I want them to scroll inside the main div vertical.
it works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but on Safari or chrome on iphone it looks
totally screwed up. Its the Section "Warum Obsthof Böhm?"

here is the link: [Obsthof-Boehm](https://nicoziegler.design/obst/)

Code für Main Div:

```css
#div_block-261-25 {
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 80px;
    height: 500px;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
    height: 500px;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Code für Content DIV

```css
#div_block-618-25 {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    text-align: left;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have 2 times `height: 500px; width: 40%;` in `#div_block-261-25`.

Then just add `flex` to your div:

```
#div_block-618-25 > div{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

It should fix your problem. (Worked on safari)

Comment: thank you, yes i set the height and width in oxygen and css custom code, fixed it. The flex setting for the divs worked fine, thank you!